# How to bringing positve number with same negative number together in C programming language

Tags: c

I have the following array

```
arr= {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, -2, -2,-3,-1,-5,-4,-7}
```

I want to convert to the following format in C programming language

```
arr= {-1, 1, -2, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, 4, -5, 5, 6, -7}
```

Comment: Nothing we know of is stopping you from doing this. Please edit your post to make it a question (and take note of the fact that "write me a function" is not a valid question here).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(const int *)a;
    int y = *(const int *)b;
    int ax = abs(x);
    int ay = abs(y);
    if(ax == ay)
        return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
    else
        return ax < ay ? -1 : ax > ay;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, -2, -2,-3,-1,-5,-4,-7};
    int i;
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    qsort(arr, size, sizeof(int), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `abs` function to find absolute value and then rearrange the array elements. You will need to search your array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort it with a special sorting function, something like this if the array has integers:

```
int compare( const void* pa , const void* pb )
{
    int a = *( int* )pa ;
    int b = *( int* )pb ;

    if( abs(a) == abs(b) )
        return a - b ;

    return abs(a) - abs(b) ;
}
```

And then call qsort() with this function and your array.